# How does a differential act when we identify $T_p(M\times N)\cong T_{p_1}M\times T_{p_2}N$?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

It's fairly common to identify the tangent space of a product manifold as
$$
T_p(M\times N)\cong T_{p_1}M\times T_{p_2}N
$$
where $p=(p_1,p_2)$, and the actual isomorphism is given by $v\in T_p(M\times N)$ is sent to $(d(\pi_M)_p(v),d(\pi_N)_p(v))$, where the $\pi_N$ and $\pi_M$ are the projections.

If we make this identification, how do differentials act on the identified elements? I mean, suppose you have a smooth map $F:M\times N\to S$, and a corresponding differential $dF_p:T_p(M\times N)\to T_{F(p)}S$.

If $v\in T_p(M\times N)$, using the isomorphism I could identify $v$ with $(v_1,v_2)$ for $v_1\in T_{p_1}M$, $v_2\in T_{p_2}N$. I'm confused on how one could evaluate $dF_p$ on $(v_1,v_2)$, since it's in a new tangent space, albeit an isomorphic one.

What would be the correct way to evaluate $dF_p(v_1,v_2)$ after this identification?

Comment: You want an isomorphism $\varphi:T_{p_1}M\times T_{p_2}N\to T_p(M\times N)$ (the inverse of the one you wrote down), for then it's just the composition $dF_p\circ \varphi$. The isomorphism you are looking for is $d i_1+d i_2$, where the $i_j$ are the obvious embeddings $M\to M\times N:x\mapsto (x,p_2)$ and $N\to M\times N:y\mapsto (p_1,y)$.

Comment: It might help to think in coordinates $(x_1,\dots,x_m;y_1,\dots,y_n)$ and write your $v$ in terms of the basis derivations.